# Get Tuple from a collection by one of its values?

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections, tuples

Is there a way to get a Tuple from a collection by only one of the Tuple's values? For example when I use this Tuple struct:

```
public struct Tuple<T1, T2> {
    public readonly T1 Item1;
    public readonly T2 Item2;
    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) { Item1 = item1; Item2 = item2;} 
}
```

Is there a way to get all Tuples that have a specific item (Item1 or Item2). I thought about some kind of HashMap since looping through a list of tuples and checking each tuple for a match is quite inefficient for large datasets.

Comment: you have to track them in some kind of collection.

Comment: alright what is a good datastructure for collecting them. Having a dictionary with a key for each item and the tuple object as a value feels pretty inefficent in storage aspects

Comment: it really depends on what `T1` and `T2` are...

Comment: and how many you have.

Comment: Why are you writing your own `Tuple` instead of using .NET's `Tuple`?  You should also *really* avoid mutable structs.

Comment: @Servy .NETs Tuple is a class right?  Wouldn't OP want ValueTuple which is a struct?

Comment: @maccettura I question their need to have a value type in the first place, but if there is actually a good reason for why they need to have a value type here, then yes, there is both a reference and value type version of tuples in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list like this:

```
List<Tuple<T1, T2>> mylist;
```

You can use LINQ to enumerate all the elements of the list searching for the first one matching a condition like this:

```
var myValue = mylist.FirstOrDefault((t) => t.Item1 == "MyKey");
```

I should add, however, that this is not really good design. See comments for details, but in my own opinion, Tuples are generally not good for serious tasks because the elements are not named. The more unnamed elements you have in your data structure the harder your code will be to read. I use dictionaries for tasks like this all the time. I don't think you should be reluctant to use a dictionary instead in this case.

Comment: Thank you @BlueMonkMN. This is a solution that works. I guess LINQ loops through all of the entries and checks for a match right? I wonder if it's possible to solve this with some kind a hashing (HashMap or so) since it's more efficient than looping through a list. Anyways good answer i will accept it if there aren't any other later :)

Comment: Sorry i mean HashMap not HashSet

Comment: The .Net equivalent of HashMap is `Dictionary`.

Comment: I dont think we should be encouraging OP to write their own Tuple struct though, maybe address that in your answer

Comment: @maccettura Done.

Comment: @CarpoSep Would you consider using a sorted List and using BinarySearch with a custom function to compare elements by your desired key value?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it appears .Net does not include any type of space efficient collection class that is based on a key extracted from the objects stored. The `KeyedCollection<>` class has the right interface, but internally stores the keys and values separately. I would suggest you would need to create your own class that implements `ILookup<>` but that allows dynamic modification (unfortunately the built-in `Lookup` class doesn't).

Comment: What about a sorted list and BinarySearch with a custom comparer?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN If you check the source, a `SortedList` keeps a sorted array of keys and a separate array of values and copies them around for every add, so not very efficient, especially if your key is a large value type.

Comment: I'm not talking about a `SortedList` but a sorted `List`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have List of `Tuple<T1, T2>` objects, you can use LINQ to get a new list containing the ones you want by specifying desired conditions. Here is an example using `Tuple<int, string>` objects:

```
 List<Tuple<int, string>> originalList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

 originalList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Tom"));
 originalList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Jim"));
 originalList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Bob"));
 originalList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Ted"));
 originalList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Hal"));
 originalList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Zim"));
 originalList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Jed"));

List<Tuple<int, string>> filteredList = originalList.Where(t => t.Item1 == 3).ToList();

// filteredList contains these:
// (3, "Bob")
// (3, "Hal")
// (3, "Jed")

List<Tuple<int, string>> anotherFilteredList = originalList.Where(t => t.Item2.StartsWith("J")).ToList();

// anotherFilteredList contains these:
// (2, "Jim")
// (3, "Jed")
```